# How can I finish proving this space to be contractible?

Tags: general-topology

> Let $S$ be a space of real sequences $(x_{1},\ldots,x_{n},0,\ldots)$, s. t. only finite number of elements are not zero and $\displaystyle \sum\limits_{j=1}^{\infty}x_{j}^2 = 1$. Let's endow $S$ with topology given by standart euclidian metric. Prove that $S$ is contractible.

So we basically need to show that there is such continuous mapping $F_{t}$, that gives $\mathrm{Id}_{S}$ when $t=0$ and constant map (to some fixed point $p\in S$) when $t=1$. Of course, say, circle is not contractible as a space, but in this case it is on some higher dimensional sphere, for example $\mathbb{S}^{2}$. It can be moved smoothly on this sphere and mapped to point on $\mathbb{S}^2$. So we can consider $(x_{1},x_{2},\ldots, x_{n},0,\ldots)\mapsto \left(x_{1}\cos\frac{\pi t}{2},\ldots, x_{n}\cos\frac{\pi t}{2},\sin\frac{\pi t}{2},0,\ldots\right)$, however, when $t=1$ points with different values of $n$ are being mapped to different points. How can I proceed from here?

I am new to topology, so any ideas are appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Could you move towards a map with fixed point $0$?

Comment: But $0\notin S$?

Comment: Given any point $p$ in $S$, would you be able to find a path from that $p$ to $(1,0,0,\ldots)$?

Comment: Yes, since this point lies on every sphere in S. So I need to take homotopy, which is given by curves on spheres, which start from these points and end in (1,0,0,...)?

Comment: @Egor Sorry; misread the question

Comment: You're almost done, because your homotopy, say $H:S\times I\to S$ is essentially a map such that when restricted to $\{p\} \times I$ is a path from $p$ to $(1,0,0,\ldots)$ with some continuity conditions. Write down formulas decently and this should work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately your formula will not produce a continuous homotopy. Consider what happens when a sequence of sequences

$$(x_{1,n},x_{2,n},0,0,\ldots)$$
converges to some

$$(y_1,0,0,0,\ldots)$$

Then you add $\sin\frac{\pi t}{2}$ at the end of both sequences giving us

$$(x'_{1,n},x'_{2,n},\sin\frac{\pi t}{2},0,\ldots)$$

which cannot possibly converg to any sequence of the form
$$(y'_1,\sin\frac{\pi t}{2},0,0,\ldots)$$

because of the mismatch on the $3$rd coordinate.

The core problem is that the place where you put $\sin\frac{\pi t}{2}$ depends on the length of $(x_1,x_2,\ldots)$ sequence. Such dependency is discontinuous.

---

But your idea is not completely broken, we can still recover a correct solution, although a bit differently. By using shifts and by fixing the coordinate on which we put $\sin\frac{\pi t}{2}$.

Define $id(x_1,x_2,\ldots)=(x_1,x_2,\ldots)$ to be the identity and let $s(x_1,x_2,\ldots)=(0,x_1,x_2,\ldots)$ be the shift operator. I leave as an exercise that the shift operator is continuous, in fact is an isometry onto image.

> **Lemma 1.** $id$ is homotopic to $s$ on the sphere.

*Proof.* Note that there is no $v\in S$ such that $s(v)=tv$ for some $t\in\mathbb{R}$. This means that

$$ts(v)+(1-t)v=0$$

has no solution in $t\in\mathbb{R}$ for $v\in S$. In particular if we define

$$F(t,v)=ts(v)+(1-t)v$$

then $\lVert F(t,v)\rVert\neq 0$ and thus

$$H(t,v)=\frac{1}{\lVert F(t,v)\rVert}F(t,v)$$

is a well defined continuous homotopy $I\times S\to S$ from $id$ to $s$. $\Box$

> **Lemma 2.** $s$ is homotopic to a constant map on the sphere.

*Proof.* Since every sequence of the form $s(v)$ starts with $0$ we can apply your idea. Except that we put $\sin\frac{\pi t}{2}$ on the $1$st coordinate, regardless of the sequence. Define

$$H:I\times S\to S$$
$$H(t,x_1,x_2,\ldots)=(\sin\frac{\pi t}{2}, \cos\frac{\pi t}{2}x_1,\cos\frac{\pi t}{2}x_2,\cos\frac{\pi t}{2}x_3,\ldots)$$

This function is now a continuous homotopy from $s$ to the constant $(1,0,0,\ldots)$ map, which I leave as an exercise. $\Box$

> **Corollary.** The sphere is contractible.

*Proof.* By lemma 1 $id$ is homotopic to $s$ and by lemma 2 $s$ is homotopic to a constant map. $\Box$